# Apex dynamic report based on LOV

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I wish to create several reports based upon a list of values - however I want to use the 'LOV.value' returned to dynamically alter the sql run. So instead of having a list of reports e.g.

```
report1
report2
report3
```

I want the underlying sql to be something along the lines of:

```
select * from reportview where reportname = 'LOV.value';
```

which translate to:

```
select * from reportview where reportname = 'report1'; /
select * from reportview where reportname = 'report2'; / 
select * from reportview where reportname = 'report3';
```

depending on which option was chosen.

Is this possible? If so how can I do this?

Note: Yes the sql would always valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the item that has the LOV in the query:

```
select * from reportview where reportname = :P123_REPORT_NAME;
```

Here P123_REPORT_NAME is the name of a page item e.g. a select list, that has the LOV that returns report1-3 associated with it.  You can use the item settings to make APEX submit the page when the value is changed, if you wish.

For a pop-up LOV there is no "submit when value changed" setting.  Instead you can create a dynamic action that fires when the item is changed and submits the page.

Comment: Hi, I've created a popup_lov and I have created a report on this page, however I see the popup LOV but the report subpage doesn't refresh / update. Am I missing something else?

Comment: Thanks this has solved the issue. I was having difficulty getting it to refresh, but it turns out I had to link the affected element to my report.